# How add standard_name to attributes NetCDF file in NCO

Tags: cdo-climate, nco

How can add variable name and units to NetCDF attribute in NCO.

```
dimensions:
lat = UNLIMITED ; // (34 currently)
lon = 42 ;
time = 360 ;

float precip(lat,lon,time) ;
  precip:_FillValue = 1.e+20f ;
  precip:missing_value = 1.e+20f ;
  precip:cell_methods = "time: sum" ;
```

`C:\nco>ncatted -a units,'precip',c,c,'mm day-1' nclimgrid_lowres_prcp_ncpdq5.nc ncatted: overwrite nclimgrid_lowres_prcp_ncpdq5.nc (y/n)? y The system cannot find the path specified. ncatted: ERROR File contains no variables or groups that match name 'precip' so attribute units cannot be changed`

Comment: Welcome to SO. The error messages supplied by NCO here seem very clear. Have you checked the command?

Comment: hope you don't mind me tagging cdo, as I offered a parallel soln with that

Answer (score 1):

Your command looks correct. Too bad it does not work :) Add `-O` to automatically overwrite the output file. Single quotes only needed around the whitespace. I have no Windows machine to test on, but try this and post any error messages:

```
ncatted -O -a units,precip,c,c,'mm day-1' nclimgrid_lowres_prcp_ncpdq5.nc
```

If that does not work try this

```
ncatted -O -a units,precip,c,c,'mm day-1' nclimgrid_lowres_prcp_ncpdq5.nc out.nc
```

Comment: ncatted -O -a name,precip,c,c,precip nclimgrid_lowres_prcp4.nc nclimgrid_lowres_prcp5.nc
ncatted -O -a unite,precip,c,c,millimeter nclimgrid_lowres_prcp5.nc nclimgrid_lowres_prcp6.nc

Answer (score 1):

To offer an alternative using cdo you can also set any attribute for variables in the following way

```
cdo setattribute,var@attr="stuff" in.nc out.nc
```

for example:

```
cdo -setattribute,precip@long_name="Precipitation" -setattribute,precip@units="mm/day" in.nc out.nc
```